# WordNet Hierarchy

Tags: nlp, nltk, semantics, wordnet

In the WordNet synsets, there are a bunch of concepts such as hyponyms, hypernys, holonyms and meronyms in the NLTK library.

Can someone explain these terms and maybe provide a few examples for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordnet is well-documented (there is even a book). This is perhaps the docs page that most directly answers your questions:
https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/wngloss7wn

Also, the terms are from linguistics, not invented by the WordNet team. So dictionaries will be useful. Or you can even get meta about it, and [look them up in Wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=hypernym&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) :-)